# Get domain class field names

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to get the field names of a class and maybe store it in a list. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this to get field names of domain class.

```
YourClass.declaredFields.each {
  if (!it.synthetic) {
    println it.name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `gormPersistentEntity` for any domain object, this works with Grails 2.4.4 at least:

```
def names = Person.gormPersistentEntity.persistentPropertyNames
//returns ['firstName', 'lastName'...]
```

you can also get natural name using `GrailsNameUtils` like so:

```
def naturalNames = Person.gormPersistentEntity.persistentPropertyNames.collect {
        grails.util.GrailsNameUtils.getNaturalName(it)
}
//returns ['First Name', 'Last Name'...]

def capitilizedNames = Person.gormPersistentEntity.persistentProperties.collect{
    it.capitilizedName
}
//returns ['FirstName', 'LastName'...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just found it out, this one works:

```
def names = grailsApplication.getDomainClass('com.foo.Person').persistentProperties.collect { it.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the fields of a class like this.

```
YourClass.fields.each { println it.name }
```

If you need to put them into a list you could use collect() or populate it within the each.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3535-Reflection