# How to get field names of grails command object?

Tags: grails

These are my Controller and Command.
Now i would like to get all fields names.
Here is the link to get field names of domain class
[Get domain class field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103173/get-domain-class-field-names).
But i need to get field names of Command as i am explaining below

```
class SocialRecruitingController 
{
 def getFieldNames()
 {

 ConnectionsAdvSearchCommand.fields.each
 {it->
   log.info(it?.name+",");
// Expecting keyword,fname,lname,title,company,school,location,country,postalCode
 }


} 

class ConnectionsAdvSearchCommand
{
String keyword

String fname;
String lname;
String title;
String company;
String school;
String location;
String country;
String postalCode;
}
}
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea.  If you can describe what you are doing with the field names and what version of Grails you are using, there is probably a better way to do this than what is being suggested below.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown why is this a bad idea? I was going to use something similar to loop through all the fields of a class and trim any string type variables. Are the methods below something that should be avoided?

Comment: @DanielBlack "why is this a bad idea?" - There are a number of concerns.  One is that doing runtime reflection like that during request processing is inefficient.  There are better ways/times to gather that info.  The question I posed above was to understand what is trying to be accomplished, and knowing that will point to better solutions.  "Are the methods below something that should be avoided?" - Yes, some of that should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
ConnectionsAdvSearchCommand.declaredFields.each{
   if(!it.synthetic) println it.name
}
```

You can also try getting the properties from ExpandoMetaClass, as

```
ConnectionsAdvSearchCommand.metaClass.properties.each{
    if(it.field) println it.name
}
```

in which case `it.field` ignores the class property from the `metaClass`.

*Grails 2.2.0*

Comment: Hi @dmahapatro thanks for your reply, after executing your code 

ConnectionsAdvSearchCommand.declaredFields.each{
                if(!it.synthetic) println "-->"+it.name
            }

I got below output

-->keyword
-->fname
-->lname
-->title
-->company
-->school
-->location
-->country
-->postalCode
-->instanceControllerTagLibraryApi
-->mimeTypesApi
-->log
-->instanceConvertersControllersApi

Few extra fields are there in output please try to give a better solution

Comment: @user2729165 Which version of Grails do you use?

Comment: -->title
-->instanceControllerTagLibraryApi
-->postalCode
-->keyword
-->location
-->school
-->lname
-->companyName
-->fname
-->country
-->metaClass

@dmahapatro after executing your code i got above output. metaClass & instanceControllerTagLibraryApi are extra fields came in output. But i need exactly those fields is there any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Grails: Listing all fields/variables in a Domain/Model

In this example, I assume your domain class name is 'Research' and the full package name is 'com.package.name.Research'

Way 1:
    Research.declaredFields.each{

```
    if(!it.synthetic)
        println it.name
}
```

Way 2:

```
def names = grailsApplication.getDomainClass('com.package.name.Research').persistentProperties.collect { 
    println it.name 
}
```

Way 3:

```
def Research domainClass = grailsApplication.getGrailsDomainClass('Research')
def persistentProperties = domainClass.getPersistentProperties()
persisentProperties.each { property ->
    println property
}
```

More info can be found at [my blog](http://binyit.blogspot.com/2014/06/grails-listing-all-fieldsvariables-in.html)

Comment: I think the question is about a non-domain class.